# How to compile a C program with #include <openssl/sha.h> library?

Tags: c, openssl

I was given a task to create a log in system, where my team is planning to store user credentials in SHA-256 encryption. I have created the code and installed OpenSSL library on my laptop. I just dont know how to compile the code because my vscode is showing fatal error: openssl/sha.h: No such file or directory
#include <openssl/sha.h>

How can I compile this and run it?

Comment: What operating system? On linux you may type `echo | gcc -E -Wp,-v -` to find the include paths, and see if they have the openssl folder present.

Comment: Begin with the "Hello, World!" program on an unfamiliar system, before moving on to something more advanced. Build it step by step.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "installed OpenSSL library on my laptop"?  It is quite common for packages to include only the library, but not the headers.  eg, something like `openssl` includes the library, but `openssl-devel` will include the headers.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the header include `<path>` to `openssl/sha.h` with the `gcc` flag `-I<path>`

On Debian based systems the header in question is installed with `apt install libssl-dev`.  It will be installed in a standard search directory so it should just work.  When it comes time to link you can get the required linker flags with `pkg-config --libs libcrypto`.